# How to install secrets safely on EC2 instances?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Context: Setting up an infra with some Auto-scaling groups and some non-scaling self-standing VMs. Some roles need secrets (private keys) which should be restricted to root or to specific users. Management is done via Puppet("serverless" - configuration is in a git repository), Ansible is also available.

- putting secrets in Puppet or git is not acceptable, as they are widely accessible
- putting secrets in EC2 User Data limits the access to the specific VM, and replicates correctly in an auto-scaling group, however it's accessibly by any unix user in the VM.
- putting secrets in secure S3 buckets is a lot of work, limits the access to specific VMs, replicates correctly in an auto-scaling group, encrypts data at rest, however it's accessibly by any unix user in the VM -- see http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2B3QUWAA7KOU/How-to-Manage-Secrets-for-Amazon-EC2-Container-Service-Based-Applications-by-Usi
- AWS KMS improves on secure S3 buckets, but I cannot find any indication of restrictions of access to its services *within the VM*.

I am under no illusion about Linux's user privileges being bulletproof. However limiting access to secrets to only the Linux root user is... useful! :-)

Comment: Something like https://www.vaultproject.io/ might be suitable

Comment: @ceejayoz -- thanks! read the intro... it is not clear to me how it could be incorporated to tighten up access.

The one angle I like is the seal/unseal. The vault could be unsealed just before spinning up a VM, and re-sealed shortly after, limiting the time-window of exposure.

Comment: It's got per-user ACLs (https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/acl.html) that should be leverageable for what you're looking to do. You'd give the root users a [particular Vault token](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/authentication.html) and limit access to sensitive stuff to that token or tokens.

Comment: @ceejayoz -- how do I get this magic token to the root user automatically without disclosing it?

Comment: I'd probably bake it into the AMI.

Comment: Right. At which point you can bake all your secrets into the AMI :-) -- vault gives you flexibility in baking only the "key" to your other secrets; then you can update your secrets.

... To expand on the "bake it into the AMI", the problem with that it is unflexible in the face of many roles. I have a couple roles where it's worth baking an AMI (ie: for autoscaling groups); I also have a couple dozen roles each needing specific secrets, not worth having a custom AMI for them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have found a viable solution:

- Use Vault or similar to manage the actual secrets, grouped by role, with short keys to unlock each set of secrets.
- Automate Instance creation with something scriptable (ie: Cloudformation, Terraform, aws cli), as part of the creation script...

  - create and populate a short-lived S3 bucket with the Vault key
  - provide a bootstrap script via EC2 userdata, which fetches the Vault key from S3 bucket

Assumptions:

- S3 bucket url randomness prevents it from (quick) discovery
- Your base AMI is safe until bootstrap completes; this means that isn't pre-rooted ;-) and doesn't come up with insecure/misconfigured services that'd make it likely to be successfully attacked in the brief time window of S3 bucket life.

Thanks to @ceejayoz for useful hints.

Comment: These are dangerous recommendations and should not be the accepted answer. Security via obscurity alone is not security at all, s3 buckets can be enumerated, tokens/keys should not be written unencrypted to disk (especially not one you don't control).